# geom_histogram with subset data, how to stop bars overlapping

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, facet-grid, geom-histogram

I am exploring a dataset of goals (goals/minute here) across years (1986-2023) for both the men's and women's side of the game in this sport. I want to visually explore subsets of the data (here <=2009 and >2009) for both game disciplines.

What I've tried is this

```
ggplot(WMGoalsAll,aes(x=GoalsMin,fill=Discipline))+
  geom_histogram(data= ~subset(., Year >"2014"),aes(y=..count..),
                 binwidth=0.02,colour="black",fill="tomato3",position=position_dodge2(preserve="single"))+ 
  geom_histogram(data= ~subset(., Year<="2014"),aes(y=..count..),
                 binwidth=0.02,position="dodge",colour="black",fill="powderblue")+
  facet_grid(Discipline~.,scales="free")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,0.3,0.02))+theme_light()+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,vjust=0.5))
```

and this gives me just the figure I want
[Freq goals/min](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTvbr.png)

... except as you can see I can't work out how to use the "position="dodge"", or one of its variations, to get the bars in each facet to sit alongside each other instead of on top. I have made subsets of the data to build separate figures and then put them together with grid.arrange but I feel the comparisons aren't as clear as they are with facet_grid or facet_wrap. Any help on how to do this gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your desired result use the complete dataset, use only one `geom_histogram` and instead of subsetting map the condition by which you want to split your data on the `fill` aesthetic. Afterwards you could set your desired fill colors via `scale_fill_manual`.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
set.seed(123)

WMGoalsAll <- data.frame(
  Year = sample(c(2010, 2020), 100, replace = TRUE),
  Discipline = sample(c("Men", "Women"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  GoalsMin = runif(100, 0, .3)
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(WMGoalsAll, aes(x = GoalsMin)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(fill = Year > 2014),
    binwidth = 0.02, colour = "black",
    position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 0.3, 0.02)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("tomato3", "powderblue")) +
  facet_grid(Discipline ~ ., scales = "free") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Much simpler, many thanks.